# How do you condense this into one query

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the following Model:

```
class ReportLayout(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ...
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name', )
```

And the following ModelManager method:

```
def for_company(self, company):
    names = self.filter(company=company).values_list('name', flat=True)
    public_ids = self.filter(company__isnull=True).exclude(
        name__in=names).values_list('id', flat=True)
    return self.filter(Q(company=company)|Q(id__in=public_ids))
```

The idea is to get all of the ReportLayouts for a company.  Those consist of:

1. ReportLayouts that belong to the company,
2. All the public/shared ReportLayouts (where company=null) that don't have a matching name in 1 above.

So, if I have 3 ReportLayouts:

```
id Name  Company
1  A     null
2  B     null
3  B     Company1
```

`for_company(Company1)` should return the ReportLayouts that have IDs 1 and 3

Seems like I should be able to write it in one query, but the best I have so far is 3.  The problem stems from the .filter/.exclude pair of functions and the missing __notin operator.

I want the ability to do `.count()` and I want the ordering that the query is providing is why I don't just do it in 2 queries.  But how I do it in one is completely eluding me.